# Another question of finding eigenvalues with parameters

Tags: linear-algebra

Let

$$A=\left(\begin{matrix}a&b&c\\a-s&b+s&c\\a-t&b&c+t\end{matrix}\right)$$

Find A's eigenvalues.

So, I did some row operations without changing the value of A's determinant, so that I got

$$A'=\left(\begin{matrix}a&b&c\\-s&0&0\\-t&0&t\end{matrix}\right)$$

But I still can't get a simple way for finding the eigenvalues. Are there more row operations I can do?

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Doing row operations generally _changes_ the characteristic polynomial, though it leaves the determinant (which is up to a sign just one coefficient of the cahracterisitic polynomial) unchanged. So the method you applied is not valid, and will give a wrong result.

Comment: So what's the correct method? Is there a method in which I can simplify the work trying to find the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: You can do row and/or column operations on the matrix $XI_3-A$, whose determinant is by definition the characteristic polynomial. This is more laborious than doing operations on $A$. Alternatively you can _conjugate_ $A$ by simple matrices, which amounts to specific combinations of row _and_ column operations; the latter respects the characteristic polynomial and does not involve $X$, but takes quite a bit of practice to apply correctly, and it is hard to produce specific simplifications using it.

Comment: Also, where did $b$ go on the way from $A$ to $A'$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Maple, the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is
$$\begin{align}
x^3 &{}+(-c-a-t-b-s)x^2 \\&{}+ (-a^2+2as+st+at+sc+tc+ab+bt)x \\&{}+ (tac-asc-2ast+scb-abt+a^2t-tsc-tcb),\end{align}$$ and it does not factor. This means the problem is pretty hopeless. The constant term is also clearly not $-\det(A')$, so either you mistyped the matrix $A$ in the first place, or you made errors in the row operations leading to $A'$ (but which would not lead to solving this problem anyway if done correctly, just to get the right constant term of the characteristic polynomial).

**Added.** With the now modified matrix, the simplest thing is to conjugate by $I_3-E_{1,2}-E_{1,3}$ (with $E_{i,j}$ an elementary matrix; conjugations means left-multiply by this matrix and right-multiply by the inverse $I_3+E_{1,2}+E_{1,3}$); this transforms $A$ into the similar matrix
$$
  A'=\begin{pmatrix}a+b+c&b&c\\0&s&0\\0&0&t\end{pmatrix},
$$
which being triangular clearly has eigenvalues $a+b+c$, $s$, and $t$, and so has$~A$.

Comment: So it isn't solvable?!

Comment: Sorry!!! There was an error in the original matrix!